# How to log spec execution result in a log file ? - jasmine

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

I'm new in Jasmine. My intend to create a reporter using jasmine. I have simple below example.

```
afterAll( function(){ 
            writeStream.write( date + " execution done " );
            writeStream.end();  
  }); 
describe("Sample test 1",function(){ 

   it("after each function ", function(){
      expect(1).toEqual(1);     
   }); 

   it("Sample test 2 ", function(){
      expect(1).toEqual(1);     
   }); 

});
```

Once both specs has been executed. I want to log the result in a JSON file. in `afterAll`. I'm struggling in get into know the solution over the internet. Can someone have idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used custom reporter. it has done what i suppose to do

https://jasmine.github.io/2.3/custom_reporter.html

Example :

```
suiteDone : function(result) {
    console.log('Suite: ' + result.description + ' was ' + result.testStatus);
    for (var i = 0; i < result.failedExpectations.length; i++) {
        console.log('AfterAll ' + result.failedExpectations[i].message);
        console.log(result.failedExpectations[i].stack);
    }
    if(result.failedExpectations.length==0){
        testStatus="pass";

    }

    suiteEndTime = currentDateTime();
    var obj = {
        "name" : suiteName,
        "testStatus" : testStatus,
        "tests" : [ testCaseName ],
        "total" : totalTestCases,
        "pass" : passedTestCaseCount,
        "fail" : failedTestCaseCount,
        "skip" : 0,
        "startTime" : parseInt(suiteStartTime),
        "endTime" : parseInt(suiteEndTime)
    };

    var fs = require('fs');
    var json = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4);
    fs.writeFile(createJsonMetadataInJsonFolder(), json, 'utf8');
}
```